# Seekable random number generator

Tags: random

Is there any exact random generator that can be seek (for example 10004th number is always X, with O(1) storage and performance)?

```
var x = new RNG(99); // seed
var y = x.at(10004); // always return same value, eg. 0.34
```

what's the algorithm or function/formula name? any language is fine.

Comment: What do you need this for? Just out of curiosity. Maybe there is a better overall solution. (See XY problem.)

Comment: to consistently checking game/battle calculation between client and server, to make sure they didn't cheat the RNG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-recursive random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125021/non-recursive-random-number-generator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't need any PRNG as long as numbers are generated deterministically using a seed and index numbers.
In addition, The output numbers are hard to guess without actually calculating it.

[HMAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) is enough for your requirement.

```
H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))
```

`K` = key(index)
`text` = message(seed)
`H` = cryptographic hash function
`ipad` = bytes of`H`'s block byte length filled with `0x36`
`opad` = bytes of`H`'s block byte length filled with  `0x5C`

Or maybe you can even do

```
H(seed,index) //like Sha256(seed + index)
```

Use mod to adjust output range

Comment: nice idea, why i didn't think of this XD